# form_for submits some extra params which are not part of that object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I want to submit some extra params which are not part of that model object. here is my code example

```
= form_for Comment.new, :url => notes_path({:pined_feed_item => ""}), :html => {class: 'form clearfix', id: 'add_post_form'}, remote: true do |form|
    .control-group
      = form.text_area :text, :placeholder => 'Post to the community', :cols => nil, :rows => nil, :class => 'mention expand-without-submit'
      = check_box_tag :pined_feed_item
      pinged post
    = submit_tag "Post your message", class: 'btn btn-success btn-mini'
```

I want to get check_box value at the controller level, but when I inspect there it gives me empty string

Comment: The problem actual problem is like this the empty value that I am getting is because of the above :url => notes_path({:pined_feed_item => ""}). Checkbox value never gets passed to server. How can I supply that value to server. I have a feeling that form is ignoring it because it is not part of model

Answer (score 1):

It gives you an empty string because you haven't set any value for it. Try using `check_box_tag` the way it is described in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag). The second argument (`pined`) is the value of the checkbox and the third one is for the state of the checkbox (if it's going to be checked or not). For example:

```ruby
...
check_box_tag 'pined_feed_item', 'pined', true
# => <input checked="checked" id="pined_feed_item" name="pined_feed_item" type="checkbox" value="pined" />
...
```

In this case the parameters array in the controller will be something like:

```ruby
# params.inspect
"...{:pined_feed_item=>"pined"}..."
```

So you can do checks in your controller based on this condition

```ruby
if params[:pined_feed_item] == 'pined'
...
end
```

Comment: Your right about the api stuff but this not the problem actual problem is like this the empty value that I am getting is because of the above :url => notes_path({:pined_feed_item => ""}). Checkbox value never gets passed to server. How can I supply its value to server. I have a feeling that form is ignoring it because it is not part of Model

Comment: Well my bad. It has to be the `url` you are using. Why do you do it this way? You are passing the same variable two times (one from within the form and one from the URL) so there might be a conflict.

Comment: its is not conflict, if I removes the above option then my params.inspect looks like this 

{"comment"=>{"text"=>""}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"notes"}

Comment: Does this happen when the checkbox is both checked and unchecked?

Comment: checkbox value never gets push to server either it checked or unchecked

Answer (score 1):

Remove `{:pined_feed_item => ""}` from your `url`. That is overwriting the value of checkbox `pined_feed_item`.

When you check the box and submit the form you will see that  `pined_feed_item"=>"1"`, if unchecked and submitted then this parameter will not be part of `params` hash.
Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your extra params?

It should be available as `params[:pined_feed_item]`.

If you like to access them with `params[:comment][:pined_feed_item]`, then you need to change your view to `check_box_tag 'comment[pined_feed_item]'`.

Comment: params[:pined_feed_item] is accessible but it binds its value according to checkbox. here is my params.inspect

{"comment"=>{"text"=>""}, "pined_feed_item"=>"", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"notes"}